# Dotnet core - Referenced Library Not Available - Inconsistent Behaviour

Tags: .net-core

Help on this would be much appreciated. I've confirmed this behaviour on three computers now but can't find any reference to it online. I guess I'm missing something.

I've written a few test applications in dotnet core 1.1 but am suddenly having difficulty adding libraries / references to other projects.

If I create a new library like this: **FooLibrary**

```
dotnet new classlib
```

And create a simple class like this:

```
namespace FooLibrary

{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string GetMyString(){ return "Here I am."; }
    }
}
```

And then create a separate project in another folder: **BarApp**

```
dotnet new console
```

Add the reference:

```
dotnet add reference ..\Foo\FooLibrary\FooLibrary.csproj
```

After restoring and building both projects and reloading the window I would expect the FooLibrary to be available in BarApp. It isn't.
In VSCode I get this error after adding the using reference:

> Could not load file or assembly 'FooLibrary ...

This is where it gets strange. If I open the project in Visual Studio Pro I have a similar warning (saying it cannot resolve the reference), but if I run restore and save I can then run the app in both Visual Studio Pro and VSCode and get the value from the class library, even though I still get all the warnings and there's no intellisense.

*In the first screenshot below note that the using statement and the new TestClass() initialisation are underlined in red and yet while debugging a value is still returned.*

[image]
[image]

Comment: I followed your steps to reproduce the error and got the same result. If I used Visual Studio and used an .sln file I didn't get any errors. This means its most likely a tooling issue since it complied and ran fine. It could be an issue with OmniSharp, or the .NET tooling. I'd create an issue on their Github pages https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn

Comment: Thanks @TravisBoatman, issue raised: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raised the issue here:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1444

Here is the response and solution in reference to the screenshot below:

*Thanks! That's what I suspected. This is a duplicate of [#963](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/963) and [#1420](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1420). Essentially, C# for VS Code 1.9 won't process projects outside of the folder opened in VS Code. So, you can open the folder above this one to get IntelliSense to work.
The good news is that the issue is already fixed. If you like, you can download [v1.10.0-beta1] and install it using the instructions here: [Installing Beta Releases](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Installing-Beta-Releases).* **DustinCampbell**

[image]